# Key value pairs into a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have pulled the key-value pairs below from a API as listed below:
summary["awayBattingTotals"],summary["homeBattingTotals"],summary["teamInfo"]

```
response;
{'namefield': 'Totals',
  'ab': '33',
  'r': '2',
  'h': '7',
  'hr': '1',
  'rbi': '2',
  'bb': '0',
  'k': '8',
  'lob': '13',
  'avg': '',
  'ops': '',
  'obp': '',
  'slg': '',
  'name': 'Totals',
  'position': '',
  'note': '',
  'substitution': False,
  'battingOrder': '',
  'personId': 0},
 {'namefield': 'Totals',
  'ab': '34',
  'r': '4',
  'h': '9',
  'hr': '2',
  'rbi': '4',
  'bb': '1',
  'k': '7',
  'lob': '13',
  'avg': '',
  'ops': '',
  'obp': '',
  'slg': '',
  'name': 'Totals',
  'position': '',
  'note': '',
  'substitution': False,
  'battingOrder': '',
  'personId': 0},
 {'away': {'id': 145,
   'abbreviation': 'CWS',
   'teamName': 'White Sox',
   'shortName': 'Chi White Sox'},
  'home': {'id': 118,
   'abbreviation': 'KC',
   'teamName': 'Royals',
   'shortName': 'Kansas City'}})
```

How can I write this into a data frame using pandas? i tried using

`pd.DataFrame.from_dict(summary)`

but this gives me the below error

`ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length`

Comment: “*this gives me an error*” Why have you elected to *not* include the full stack trade of the error to which you’re referring? [ask]

Comment: error included in description

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right path. This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
dict = [{'namefield': 'Totals',
  'ab': '33',
  'r': '2',
  'h': '7',
  'hr': '1',
  'rbi': '2',
  'bb': '0',
  'k': '8',
  'lob': '13',
  'avg': '',
  'ops': '',
  'obp': '',
  'slg': '',
  'name': 'Totals',
  'position': '',
  'note': '',
  'substitution': False,
  'battingOrder': '',
  'personId': 0},
 {'namefield': 'Totals',
  'ab': '34',
  'r': '4',
  'h': '9',
  'hr': '2',
  'rbi': '4',
  'bb': '1',
  'k': '7',
  'lob': '13',
  'avg': '',
  'ops': '',
  'obp': '',
  'slg': '',
  'name': 'Totals',
  'position': '',
  'note': '',
  'substitution': False,
  'battingOrder': '',
  'personId': 0},
 {'away': {'id': 145,
   'abbreviation': 'CWS',
   'teamName': 'White Sox',
   'shortName': 'Chi White Sox'},
  'home': {'id': 118,
   'abbreviation': 'KC',
   'teamName': 'Royals',
   'shortName': 'Kansas City'}}]
pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data contained in `summary["teamInfo"]` is different from `summary["awayBattingTotals"]` and `summary["homeBattingTotals"]`. You can seperate them into 2 data group:

```
batting_totals = [
 {'namefield': 'Totals',
  'ab': '33',
  'r': '2',
  'h': '7',
  'hr': '1',
  'rbi': '2',
  'bb': '0',
  'k': '8',
  'lob': '13',
  'avg': '',
  'ops': '',
  'obp': '',
  'slg': '',
  'name': 'Totals',
  'position': '',
  'note': '',
  'substitution': False,
  'battingOrder': '',
  'personId': 0},
 {'namefield': 'Totals',
  'ab': '34',
  'r': '4',
  'h': '9',
  'hr': '2',
  'rbi': '4',
  'bb': '1',
  'k': '7',
  'lob': '13',
  'avg': '',
  'ops': '',
  'obp': '',
  'slg': '',
  'name': 'Totals',
  'position': '',
  'note': '',
  'substitution': False,
  'battingOrder': '',
  'personId': 0}
]

batting_df = pd.DataFram.from_dict(batting_totals)
```

output 1:

```
    namefield       ab  r   h   hr  rbi bb  k   lob avg ops obp slg name    position    note    substitution    battingOrder    personId
0   Totals          33  2   7   1   2   0   8   13                  Totals                      False                           0
1   Totals          34  4   9   2   4   1   7   13                  Totals                      False                           0
```

and

```
team_info = 
{'away': {'id': 145,
          'abbreviation': 'CWS',
          'teamName': 'White Sox',
          'shortName': 'Chi White Sox'},
 'home': {'id': 118,
          'abbreviation': 'KC',
          'teamName': 'Royals',
          'shortName': 'Kansas City'}
}

team_info_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(team_info)
```

output 2:

```
                away            home
id              145             118
abbreviation    CWS             KC
teamName        White Sox       Royals
shortName       Chi White Sox   Kansas City
```

From these 2 dataframe, you will probably need to find a way to map the game in `batting_df` to `team_info_df`